# Opening new url with javascript in a new window but can't read value because it's null

Tags: javascript, url

So I have my code but when I enter it into the console in chrome it comes back "TypeError: Cannot read property 'trigger' of null"
It's because con doesn't exist yet. How can I fix it?

```
var win = window.open("https://www.sitetest2.robloxlabs.com/upgrades/payment?ap=100");
var con = win.document.getElementById("submit-button-wrapper")

function Loop()
{
    con.trigger("click")
}

Loop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the window to get you an element that does not exist. Once that window is opened if you run the following in the console:

```
window.document.getElementById("submit-button-wrapper")
```

Then the return value is null because there is no element on the page with an id of `submit-button-wrapper` In fact that identifier is not mentioned at all. (as a class even) Even if I wait for the page to fully load that element is never added to the document.

If an element does not exist, you cannot get it. Simple as that.

If the element is created due to an Ajax load then you need to hook into that and get the element after the Ajax load has occurred.

Comment: When the page is fully loaded the element is existing. But I can't call it because it isn't loaded, correct?

Comment: I was trying to call by Id but I meant to call by ClassName. I put it in and now it says undefined is not a function.

    var win = window.open("https://www.sitetest2.robloxlabs.com/upgrades/payment?ap=100");
    var con = win.document.getElementByClassName("btn-medium btn-primary")
    
   function Loop()
   {
     con.trigger("click")
    }

    Loop()

Comment: var win = window.open("https://www.sitetest2.robloxlabs.com/upgrades/payment?ap=100");
var con = win.$('#submit-button-wrapper > a')

function Loop()
{
 con.trigger("click")
}

Loop()

is what it should be. Still comes back undefined is not a function

Comment: Unfortunately this cannot be tested by someone without an account on your site as they cannot reach the payment gateway.

Comment: The site I am using is a test site by the company ROBLOX. Accounts are free and so are the payments (only on the test site).

Comment: Creating an account to fix the bugs in your code goes beyond what this site is for. You understand the problem (you cannot get an element until it exists) so the solution is easy. Wait until the element exists until you try to get it. If the element is created on page load it will exist, so the only other explanation is that it is created after the page has loaded. Find the code that creates the element and after it is created get the element.